# A pattern to find out if data in a dialog-window was modified by the user?

Tags: design-patterns, database, gui

I think about if there is a pattern or another intelligent solution for that problem. I am searching for a more generalized and reusable solution.

I load an existing and still persistent row/object from a database and display this data in a editable dialog-window to the user.

When closing the window I want to know if the user modfied the data in that dialog. e.g. I should write that modifications back to the database instance and store it.

I could simply check each attribut from the window with the database. Or I could add event-handlers to each component of the window that will set a `isModified`-flag or something like that. But this doesn't sounds intelligent to me.

Maybe there is a more generalized reusable solution for that?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

> I could simply check each attribut from the window with the database

Its better to check the data has changed before sending it to the DB. So I would read the data to be displayed into local storage (I found the best way was a map array of variables keyed by control name), copy that into the GUI control and then check the differences when the GUI is closed - if the data is different, then send it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think your two options basically nail it. I tend to prefer the flag option. If you have a UI that's appropriate, this can be combined with the Command pattern (execute methods will store the current value of isModifies; undo methods restore the saved value).

Answer (score 0):

1. Event-handlers: useful when you want to know in "realtime" if something has changed
2. Simple check: useful when you want to **lazily** know if something has changed

As it is important for you to know this when the window is closing, I'll go with option 2.